# __get() fetching children, detect if child exists

Tags: php

I have a PHP Entity class, where each entity may contain multiple child Entities, and am using `__get()` to step down from a parent to find its children.

```
$parent->Child1->Child2->Child3->value;

public function __get($name) {
    $name = preg_replace('/![A-z ]+/', '', $name);
        // $child = getByName($name, $parentid)
    if ($child = $this->getByName(str_replace('_', ' ', $name), $this->id)) {
    return $child;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, if any of the child entities don't exist, it fails with "Trying to get property of non-object ..." is there a better way of preventing this, other than doing the following?

```
if(isset($parent) && is_object($parent->Child1) && is_object($parent->Child1->Child2)
```

Comment: How would you expect that to work? You can refactor the code to something like `if($child = $parent->Child) { if($child2 = $child->Child2) { if ($child3 = $child2->Child) { ... }}}`. Or, if you don't mind losing intellisense, you can wrap the chain in a helper function like `if($c3 = $parent->getDescendant('Child1', 'Child2', 'Child3')) { $c3->value; }`

Comment: @DCoder This seems like the logical answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two workarounds:

---

Nested `if`s:

```
    if($child = $parent->Child) {
      if($child2 = $child->Child2) {
        if($child3 = $child2->Child3) {
          // use $child3->Value
        }
      }
    }
```

---

Helper function (of course, this approach loses IntelliSense):

```
    function getDescendant($parent) {
      $args = func_get_args();
      $names = array_slice($args, 1);
      $result = $parent;
      while(count($names)) {
        $name = array_shift($names);
        if(isset($result->$name)) {
          $result = $result->$name;
        } else {
          return NULL;
        }
      }
      return $result;
    }

    if($c3 = getDescendant($parent, 'Child1', 'Child2', 'Child3')) {
      // use $c3->value;
    }
```